Kubuntu does not boot after upgrade to 24.04.1
Config: Notebook HP Omen 15,
Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with all recent updates, perfectly working.
I've got a notice from update manager that a new version 24.04.1 LTS is available, and decided to upgrade.
In the very end of the stage of package installation, before cleanup, my notebook has lost network connection, probably, due to incorrect drivers loaded during upgrade, or something else, and was unable to download some packages.
Soon after that, upgrade process has finished with the error message saying that it has failed.
I have rebooted the PC, and now OS doesn't boot at all. Soon after appearance of the Kubuntu logo, I am dropped in the maintenance command prompt, suggesting to inspect logs and type exit to continue booting.
journalctl -xb shows following error messages:
systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2uuid-50DE\x2d5874: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-50DE\x2d5874.device/start timed out.
systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-50DE\x2d5874.device - dev-disk-by-uuid/50DE-5874.

ID 50DE-5874 belongs to /boot/efi partition.
There are some other similar records, listing UUIDs, belonging to all NVME drives in my notebook. I can see them on the screen during OS startup if I press ESC.
I've tried advice to remove "quiet splash" from grub command line - it didn't help.
Tried to choose other kernel from Grub menu, also does not help. I've got 6.8, 6.5 and 5.19 kernel versions, all of them fail to boot, both in recovery and "normal" mode.
I've tried to continue update in that emergency command prompt by issuing command apt upgrade -f.
Unfortunately, this does not help too. APT lists many packages that are obsolete and could be removed (clearly, because Cleanup stage was not run), then it suggests to install two new packages, "mailcap" and "mime-support", but fails to download them.
Further examination shows that network drivers are not loaded.
ifconfig shows only lo and docker0 network interfaces.
lshw -C network displays Realtek Ethernet and Intel WiFi adapters, saying that Ethernet adapter is disabled, and WiFi is unclaimed.
lspci -k displays these adapters too.
I've tried to restart systemd-networkd service with the command systemctl restart systemd-networkd.
systemctl status systemd-networkd shows that it was successfully started, but network interfaces still don't appear.
I've tried to boot Kubuntu 24.04.1 from a live USB stick. It successfully boots and connects to network. I can also see all my NVME drives with data on them.
I'd like very much to avoid reinstalling OS.
Is it possible to load network and other drivers from that maintenance command prompt and continue broken upgrade?
